# what is the background theory that Z3 uses to prove constraints unsat

Tags: constraints, z3

The method to get the sat result is kind of straightforward, you can use some search algorithms like heuristic search to get a solution. But how does z3 get the unsat result like x < 2 && x > 2

I searched for some articles related to z3 but didn't don't know how. I would be very grateful if someone could give me the answer or recommend me relevant information

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very programming related, maybe it is better to ask it at the [cs.se] site instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the field of "decision procedures." There's a ton of literature you can find, including a couple of books:

- Daniel Kroening and Ofer Strichman's book: https://www.decision-procedures.org
- "Calculus of Computation" by Bradley and Manna (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-74113-8) is also an excellent resource.

The YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgAVIqraCHo does a good job of introducing how to program z3.

Leonardo has tons of slide decks you can go through: https://leodemoura.github.io/slides.html

I'd caution you that your assertion *The method to get the sat result is kind of straightforward, you can use some search algorithms like heuristic search to get a solution* is extremely simplistic. While that's the basic idea, it ignores the domain knowledge that makes SMT all about "theories." Finding models efficiently is a very difficult problem indeed, and there's been tons of research in this area. But I trust the above links should get you started in looking at the theory behind these solvers.